# on my website, some of my stuff is covered by the header. is there anyway i can fix this

Tags: javascript, html, css

The header covers my websites and half of my opening welcome is covered, what css properties can I use or changed can I make to fix this?

I was experimenting my stuff and now it looks weird. You can see it at http://algninja.000webhostapp.com/

```css
body {
    background: purple;
}
div.a {
    margin:25px 10px 25px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: gold;
    color: purple;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 25px;
}
#header {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#13AFF2;
    z-index:2;
}
button.projectsbutton {
    color: purple;
    border:none;
    background: gold;
    padding:15px 32px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "header"> 
        <button onclick = "window.location.href = 'https://google.com';"class = "projectsbutton"><b>projects</b></button>
    </div>
    <div class = "a">
        <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
        <h3>Look around, and see what u can find</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add width: 100%; to button.projectsbutton

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to `div.a`

```
position: relative;
top: 100px; /* or whatever value you like */
```

or you can increase to `top margin value` from `div.a` if you change the margin line from

```
margin: 25px 10px 25px 10px;
```

to

```
margin: 100px 10px 25px 10px;
```